# Remove Child? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I'm incredibly new to AS3, and barely know my way around. 
I built a simple colouring book game, essentially changing some of the graphics of a tutorial, and replacing numbers and sizes to fit what I wanted to achieve. I then built a menu screen in a seperate scene and linked the two with code snippets and buttons to go back and forth.

The colour pickers are generated when the game is ran, however an issue I seem to be facing is that when I go back to my main menu, they are still there.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how I can fix this? I'm sure it's a rather simple fix. I can provide the code from the tutorial if needed

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right you need removechild this color to remove one color from stage... Maybe you need removechildren to remove all color, whin are on stage... Try this two way